# Getting list of files inside a Java applet's JAR

Tags: java, jar, applet

I'm trying to fetch list of files using a method that apparently works well with non-applet Java code.

I'm fully aware it's messy; I'm just trying to get this to work for a school assignment. (I'm no fan of Java.)

```
        CodeSource src = MemoryButtonHelper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
        if (src == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        URL jar = src.getLocation();
        System.out.println("Loading from " + jar);

        JarFile zf=new JarFile(jar.toString()); //jar.openStream());

        final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = zf.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            final JarEntry ze = entries.nextElement();

            if(ze.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || ze.getName().endsWith(".png"))
            {
                System.out.println("Adding " + ze.getName());
                slikeList.add(ze.getName());
            }
        }
        zf.close();
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a security exception.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getProtectionDomain)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.getProtectionDomain(Class.java:2106)
    at hr.tvz.programiranje.java.deseti.helpers.MemoryButtonHelper.getSlike(MemoryButtonHelper.java:75)
        … ad nauseam …
```

According to Java Console, exception appears to occur before the `println("Loading from " + jar)`.

This is a bonus point assignment which specifically says that we must fetch the list of images from the JAR file. Since this is my first encounter with the applets, I'm not sure what I can do to fetch the list of images.

Comment: `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()` A security update in the late 1.5 or early 1.6 era Java now provides the original source of the Jar (from the site) as the location of the Jar, for both applets and JWS apps. (even trusted ones).  Or, the shorter version.  That will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..we must fetch the list of images from the JAR file.

Who put them in there in the first place?  If the answer is 'we did', the solution is simple.

- Include a list of image path/names at a known location (e.g. `images/imagelist.txt`) in the Jar.
- Obtain a reference to the list using `getResource(String)`.
- Read the list (probably using a line reader).

---

> Apparently they want me to list the contents of the jar as-is, without extra metadata.

OK.  If you can form an URL to (and thereby an `InputStream` from) the Zip file, it is possible to establish a [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) from it.  This should work whether the URL is to a Zip/Jar cached on the local file-system *or* still at the server.

1. Get an URL to the Jar.
2. Establish a `ZipInputStream` from the URL.
3. Iterate the entries using [`getNextEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#getNextEntry%28%29) until `null`
4. Examine each one for a potential match and if it does, add it to an `ArrayList`.

Of course, you'll still need signed & trusted code to call for the protection domain.

---

> Images are definitely in the same JAR

To get an URL to the Jar, try this (untested).  Let's assume the applet is `com.our.BookingApplet`.

1. Obtain an URL to the Jar in which the class resides, using
    
   `URL urlToApplet = this.getClass().getResource("/com/our/BookingApplet.class")`
2. `String[] parts = urlToApplet.toString().split("!")` will provide two parts, the first will be a `String` representation of the Jar URL.
3. Use that `String` to establish an `URL`, then use the `URL` as described in the previous update.

Comment: I thought of that. Unfortunately, I don't think the assignment wants me to do that. Apparently they want me to list the contents of the jar as-is, without extra metadata.

Comment: Images are definitely in the same JAR. If I understand you correctly, if I avoid getting the path to the JAR using `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`, there is absolutely no issue with using `ZipInputStream`, `JarInputStream` et al?

Comment: *"there is absolutely no issue"*  There should be no *security restrictions* on it.  Other issues I don't speak for.

Comment: It was a while before I had the opportunity to try this out. I had to additionally strip the `jar:` prefix from the URL. Additionally, I struggled a bit before realizing that this is not file access and finding out that getting the input stream obtained from `URLConnection` which is obtained from `java.net.URL` is required. I'll post my code in another answer, and I'll accept your answer. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks go to Andrew Thompson for his [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788308/39974)! Definitely upvote his answer instead (or in addition) to this one, since without his help, I wouldn't be able to figure this out.

Here is the portion of the code which I came up with to use to fetch list of `.jpg` and `.png` files inside the JAR file. Note that you probably need to change the name of the package where `MemoryGame` class is stored, as well as change the name of the class itself.

```
        List<String> slikeList = new ArrayList<String>();

        URL urlToApplet = MemoryGame.class.getResource("/com/whoever/whatever/gui/MemoryGame.class");
        String[] parts = urlToApplet.toString().split("!");
        String jarURLString = parts[0].replace("jar:", "");
        System.out.println("Loading from " + jarURLString);

        URL jar = new URL(jarURLString);

        URLConnection jarConnection = jar.openConnection();
        JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(jarConnection.getInputStream());

        JarEntry je = jis.getNextJarEntry();
        while(je != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Inspecting " + je);
            if(je.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || je.getName().endsWith(".png"))
            {
                System.out.println("Adding " + je.getName());
                slikeList.add(je.getName());
            }
            je = jis.getNextJarEntry();
        }
```

In case you wonder, `slike` means `images` in Croatian since a lot of variables named in the  exercise specification are in Croatian.

Answer (score 0):

Only "Signed" applets are allowed to access file system. If the jar file which you are reading from is located on your local file system, you will need to sign the applet first.

See [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) link for more information on how to sign applet.

Comment: Does the same apply for reading contents of an applet stored on an HTTP server?

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, apparently, unsigned applets can freely access contents of a JAR stored on an HTTP server. Also, even signing with an "untrusted", self-generated certificate did not allow the applet to access itself when it was opened in-browser from the local filesystem. I also suggest http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html as a more readable tutorial.